# Why does redirecting stderr make my App Engine deployment failing consistently?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I am deploying a trivial App Engine Standard Environment app. (Literally the shortest possible, a Python 3 "hello world".)  I am using Macbook with zshell.

If I redirect standard error to file, I get an error (below) every time.

```
  gcloud app deploy -q  2>>err.log
```

If I omit the redirection, it succeeds every time.

There is no difference between using `>` or `>>`. Redirecting with a pipe, e.g. to `grep`, does not cause the problem.

So this is a "solution" (by sending output through a passthrough grep) that does what I need and does not trigger the problem, but this is very roundabout.

```
  gcloud app deploy -q 2>&1 >/dev/null |egrep "." >> err.txt
```

Note that I use `-q`, so waiting for my `Y` for approval is not the issue.

The error is this. (Identifiers were anonymized.)

```
..................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build BUILD_ID status: FAILURE
Build error details: Failed to download at least one file. Cannot continue.

Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/BUILD_ID?project=PROJECT_ID
```

Looking at the logs, I see this.

```
starting build "BUILD_ID"
FETCHSOURCE
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "fetcher"
Step #0 - "fetcher": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcs-fetcher
Step #0 - "fetcher": Fetching manifest gs://staging.joshua-playground.appspot.com/ae/BUILD_ID/manifest.json.
Step #0 - "fetcher": Processing 728 files.
Step #0 - "fetcher": Failed to fetch gs://staging.my-project.appspot.com/BUILD_ID, will no longer retry: fetching "gs://staging.my-project.appspot.com/BUILD_ID" with timeout 1h0m0s to temp file "/workspace/.download/staging.joshua-playground.appspot.com-BUILD_ID": err SHA mismatch, got "SHA_VALUE", want "SHA_VALUE"
Step #0 - "fetcher": Failed to download at least one file. Cannot continue.
Finished Step #0 - "fetcher"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcs-fetcher" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: did the seven builds that failed were with the same error?

Comment: @SoniSol Yes, same error

Comment: I figured out that simply redirecting stderr causes the problem. Why? How can I deploy but capture output?

Comment: I just tried in bash with sdk v. 319 to deploy a standard GAE GO service, and it worked even if redirecting stderr to a file. Might be limited to flex. I'll try a couple more things...

Comment: My application was Standard Environment, Python3

Comment: This was on Macbook with zshell

Comment: Just tried with python3, and it fails in bash and zsh, but go works in both shells. Not sure why... but at least we now know it's language-dependent (did not try other languages to say if it's isolated to python or not).

Comment: @jofre Good to know that you can reproduce it.

Comment: This ia an issue on the plattform, Google has it already reported on https://issuetracker.google.com/175803946  and they are updating there the updates, I would recommend you to star the issue as well as click on the `+1` to get the updates on your email.

Comment: @SoniSol Indeed, there is an issue because I created one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has confirmed this issue. Please track it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175803946).